# Get a list of strings that contain a specified character from an array of string

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I just had an interview, and the interviewer asked me the following question:

> From an array of String (English words), write a function that returns all the words that contain a character.

I initially proposed something like:

```
public static List<String> find(String[] array, char c) {
     if(null ==  array || array.length == 0)
          return null;

     List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
     for(String s : array) {
          if(s.indexOf(c) > -1) {
               res.add(s);
          }
     }
     return res;
}
```

Then, the interviewer asked me to optimize my solution, what kind of data structure could be used. (She said my solution is brute-force)

I still don't see how I can optimize this. Any ideas?

Comment: can you use contains on a char? isn't indexOf?

Comment: @Leo you are right, my bad.

Comment: np. but contains does not make it brute-force. I am also curious to see the answer of this question. Was she expecting you to use indexes? :-)

Comment: @Leo She asked which data structure could be used to optimize this. How would you use indexes in this case?

Comment: Is it OK to use java 8?

Comment: @Bohemian how would you use java 8 to optimize?

Comment: My only comment would be I'd rather see an empty array returned than null.  But that's opinion tbh.  I can't see how this can be improved

Comment: Also, these kind of interview questions are pointless.  A discussion about why and when you might want to optimise this further would be more fruitful.

Comment: The only thing I see about optimizing, is about reading carefully the intial question: "From an array of String (**ENGLISH WORDS**), write etc." => you should search for a characted only if it's a valid English character, regarding its ascii code. Apart from that, I don't see how to optimize.

Comment: @saadtaame with java 8 you can do it in one line (ie much less code), but that's only a "coding" optimization assuming "less code" is desirable (which I agree with). Execution speed would be similar though. I think Lashane's answer may be what she was looking for, but that could be considered "bad coding" because it's an optimization that is not required for correct behaviour and there's nothing in the question to suggest this method would get called more than once on the same String array with different search characters. If that is a requirement, it should be made clear by the interviewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot optimize this function further, but I suppose interviewer wanted to hear something like this:

If we need to perform this operation several times on the same array, we can use following class (writing in pseudo code):

```
class FastStringArrayContainsChar {
    private Map<Char, Set<String>> index = new HashMap<Char, Set<String>>();
    public FastStringArrayContainsChar(String[] input) {
        for (String s: input) {
            for (int i=0; i<s.length; s++) {
                char c = s.charAt(i);
                if (index.contains(c))
                    index.get(c).put(s);
                else
                    index.put(c, new HashSet<String>(){{this.put(s);}});
            }
        }
    }
    public List<String> containsChar(char c) {
        return new ArrayList<String>(index.get(c));
    }
}
```

Comment: Interviewer did not give any context, I should had probably asked... but your answer makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To check that the `ith` string contains character `c`, you check it letter by letter and return once found.

```
boolean check(String s, char c)
{   for(int i = 0, n = s.length(); i < n; i++)
       if(s[i] == c)
          return true;
    return false;
}
```

This does not change the worst-case time but might run fast in practice. Other than this I don't see how you can further improve code (i'm assuming that no other information was given regarding words in array).

Comment: isn't it what indexOf() is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps input array contains duplicates. It's using more memory though

```
public static List<String> find(String[] array, char c) {
     if(array == null || array.length == 0) {
        return null;
     }
     Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
     List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
     for(String s : array) {
        if (map.containsKey(s)) {
            if (map.get(s)) {
                res.add(s);
            }
        } else {
            if(s.indexOf(c) > -1) {
                 map.put(s, true);
                 res.add(s);
            } else {
                map.put(s, false);
            }
        }

     }
     return res;
}
```